# npm install ERR! code ERESOLVE - While resolving: angular-user-idle@3.0.0

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I am using

- Angular 14.2.6
- Node 16.17.0
- Npm 8.15.0

This is the output of `ng version`

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 14.2.6
Node: 16.17.0
Package Manager: npm 8.15.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 14.2.6
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.1402.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular      14.2.6
@angular-devkit/core               14.2.6
@angular-devkit/schematics         14.2.6
@angular/cdk                       14.2.5
@angular/flex-layout               14.0.0-beta.41
@angular/material                  14.2.5
@angular/material-moment-adapter   14.2.5
@schematics/angular                14.2.6
rxjs                               7.5.7
typescript                         4.8.4
```

When I do `npm instll` to update my packages, I get following error:

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: angular-user-idle@3.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@14.2.6
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~14.2.6" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0" from @angular/cdk@14.2.5    
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!     @angular/cdk@"^14.2.5" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/cdk@"^14.0.0" from @angular/flex-layout@14.0.0-beta.41
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/flex-layout
npm ERR!       @angular/flex-layout@"^14.0.0-beta.41" from the root project      
npm ERR!     1 more (@angular/material)
npm ERR!   6 more (@angular/flex-layout, @angular/forms, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^13.3.0" from angular-user-idle@3.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/angular-user-idle
npm ERR!   angular-user-idle@"^3.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@13.3.11
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^13.3.0" from angular-user-idle@3.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/angular-user-idle
npm ERR!     angular-user-idle@"^3.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I understand I could try to use `npm install --force` or `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` as suggested in two last line in the error message above, however, the recommendation does not look encouraging given that it says "***...to accept and incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution*.**"

I am not sure how to proceed?  I dont think downgrading npm/node is a good suggestion either.

**UPDATE**

Following @skinks suggestion and adding "overrides" section to package.json like:

```
{
  ...
  ,
  "overrides": {
    "angular-user-idle": {
      "@angular/common": "$@angular/common", 
      "@angular/core": "$@angular/core"
    }
  },
  ...
```

leads to `npm audit fix` producing following:

```
# npm audit report

angular  *
Severity: moderate
angular vulnerable to regular expression denial of service (ReDoS) - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-m2h2-264f-f486
Angular (deprecated package) Cross-site Scripting - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-prc3-vjfx-vhm9
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/angular
```

**UPDATE 2**

Following @skinks suggestion, I found following references to "angular" (angularjs) in my **package-lock.json**:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to override the peer dependency of the `angular-user-idle` package:

###### package.json

```json
{
  ...
  "overrides": {
    "angular-user-idle": {
      "@angular/common": "$@angular/common", // means: use the version from the project instead of the one that the package actually depends on
      "@angular/core": "$@angular/core"
    }
  }
}
```

This approach is preferable to the `--force` flag because you have fine control over the dependencies.

Comment: Thank you.  Mind commenting on the **UPDATE** section?

Comment: The warning from the update block is coming from a different package because it refers to the `angular` package which is AngularJS (different from Angular). You most likely have updated or added another package. It's possible to find out which package is that by inspecting your `package-lock.json` — locate the `angular` dependency and see what's using it.

Comment: Thank you.  I did find this in my package-lock.json    ```... "node_modules/angular": { "version": "1.8.3", "license": "MIT", "peer": true},...``` but I am not sure what to do next

Comment: Find the package that depends on this one. There should be something like `"package": {... dependencies: {... "angular":... } }` in the package-lock.json. It's possible that you don't need the `package` at all.

Comment: Thank you, I added what I found under **UPDATE 2**.  Thanks again.

Comment: Alright, it looks like your project (i.e. your package.json file) lists `angular` as a dev (!) dependency. This makes no sense, the package should be definitely removed from there. Your screenshot also includes `angular-material` as one of the dependencies. This one should also be removed as it's an AngularJS package. The Angular counterpart is `@angular/material`.

Comment: sorry, I am new to Angular.  How would I perform these 2 changes?  Much appreciated

Comment: No worries, just remove the `"angular": "^1.6.0"` line from the package.json. Regarding the other package, `angular-material`, you may have it in the package.json as well. If so, remove it, otherwise follow the dependency trail all the way up and (most likely) remove the topmost package from the package.json.

Comment: I removed ```angular": "^1.6.0``` and ```angular-material": "^1.1.24``` from **package.json** and added to **package.json** the **overrides** section as you suggested in your answer.  That did add some changes to my **custom-theme.scss** file and **index.html** and **styles.css** files, all seem to be related to Angular Material.  But all appears to be working fine.  Thank you so much!!!

Comment: and thank you for a quite good learning experience.  Much appreciated!

Comment: given that I use **angular-user-idle**, I assume that is also AngularJS.  I guess I should be using different library, like **@angular-user-idle**?  Maybe that would remove need to user the **override**?

Comment: `angular-user-idle` is actually for Angular, you can read that on their NPM page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-user-idle

Answer (score 1):

`angular-user-idle` has angular 13 as dependency, there is not much else to do than to try the `--force` install to see if the library works well with Angular 14.

Since Angular 14 doesn't bring much breaking changes, it should be fine.

Comment: Sure, but if i use ```npm  install --force```, it looks like it is OK but it then suggests me to run ```npm audit fix```, which then returns the same ERR as posted.  The ```ng serve``` will run; however, it seam seams that I still have the same issue?  Also, next time I run ```npm install```, I get same problem

Comment: The error will only happen on install and when evaluating the dependencies so not when running.

Comment: That seams to be happening.  But ```npm install``` is something that is run often.  It feels like I am bypassing important part of upgrading dependencies properly and according to my reading.  Same is what the error suggests "*......to accept and incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.*".  Sounds like a serious smell that could cause lots of issues in the future.

Comment: One should not run `npm i` often without a specific package. prefer `npm ci`.

Comment: ```npm ci``` throws the same error.  I know about it but I thought it is recommended to be used in ci/cd, not regular development where I see most people recommend doing npm install.  However, regardless, still same issue.  ```npm install --force``` solves (apparently) but doing npm ci again produces same problem